# Doing a fluid responsive gallery item with categories selecting with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, filtering, image-gallery

I'm trying to make a responsive and fluid gallery, something like this : http://dev-so12.fr/Akram/murals/

By clicking on one of the category, images disapears or appears to let only the images of the category visible.

I would like the same behavior. I'm working with twitter bootstrap and I tried different way of doing this. The first one was with this markup :

```
<div class="existing liste container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="243" height="150" src="http://localhost/Sites/FonciereRegion/Site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hp8.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="hp8">          
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    bla
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="243" height="150" src="http://localhost/Sites/FonciereRegion/Site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hp6.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="hp6">          
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    bla
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="243" height="150" src="http://localhost/Sites/FonciereRegion/Site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hp4.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="hp4">          
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    blabla
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="243" height="150" src="http://localhost/Sites/FonciereRegion/Site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hp2.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="hp2">          
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    blabla
                </div>
            </div>
            </div><div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="243" height="243" src="http://localhost/Sites/FonciereRegion/Site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bati1.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="bati1">  
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    blabla
                </div>
            </div>
            </div></div>
```

But this has the problem that every 4 images a new row is created, so if I delete one image, it will not have the good behavior.

The other markup I could think of was the same but only that I have one general row and then only span3 divs

The issue with this markup is that I don't know how to get rid of the margin of the fifth image, and the tenth ... I could do the trick with some javascript. But If I could avoid it, that would be great, so if anyone has any idea, I would be glad to hear about it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at Filtrify, a HTML5 and jQuery tagging and filtering plug-in. It uses the HTML5 `data-` attribute to store metadata (additional data) about stuff i.e. pictures - date, artist, genre, price etc.

It's well documented with plenty of [examples](http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/music.html).